# How to detect returning visitors to a site

Tags: javascript, session, cookies, local-storage

I need to be able to style a page different for a returning visitor.
I am trying to do it using localStorage here is what I have so far.

1). check if visit flag is set and if it is add a class to the body

```
if (localStorage.getItem("visit") !== null) {
    $('body').addClass('returning');
   }
```

2). add the flag to localStorage if it doesn't exist

```
if (localStorage.getItem("visit") == null) {
    localStorage.setItem("visit", 1);
   }
```

the problem is that the first time the page loads this code works as the flag does not exist but after a page refresh the flag exists and I become a returning visitor

How can I detect a returning visitor only after a user comes back to the site and not on page reload?

Comment: Store a date-time and make it time sensitive? Can also play around with `document.referrer`

Comment: @charlietfl yeah I haven't tried storing a date-time but `document.referrer` has the same problem on page reload the referrer will change to my site

Comment: Right but combination of referrer and storage might get you what you want. Or just make it time sensitve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For every user, store a `timestamp`, instead of just a `boolean` value**

*Code Snippet*

```
// When a user visits your web-page
var timestamp = localStorage.getItem("timestamp");

if (timestamp !== null) {
    // taking visiting-gap as 15 minutes
    var epochGap = 900;

    // convert timestamp to seconds
    var jsTimestamp = (new date(timestamp).getTime())/1000;
    var currentTimestamp = (new date(timestamp).getTime())/1000;

    // Mark visitor as returning if coming after the visiting-gap
    if (jsTimestamp > (currentTimestamp + epochHour)) {
        $('body').addClass('returning');
    }
}

// Save timestamp on first visit
if (localStorage.getItem("timestamp") == null) {
    var timestamp = new Date().getTime();

    localStorage.setItem("timestamp", timestamp);
}
```

Comment: this code seems to work with some slight modifications my question now is if a visitor comes to the site and stays more that the visiting-gap they'll become a returning visitor too not sure if this matters but it's just a question that came to mind.

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted

Answer (score 0):

This is something that Google Analytics did as standard! The way they do it is to have several parts to the stored data (in the case of GA is a cookie, but local storage is fine) - most importantly, time of last pageview, session id and visitor id. The basic idea is that when the user visits the site they get a user id, a session id, and a time stamp for their pageview, all in the same cookie. Then if they load a page and the last page load time stamp recorded is >30 minutes ago the session is judged to be expired and a new session begins. You could decide when your sessions expire and judge a pageview to be part of a return visit if the previous pageview was a certain amount of time ago. Remember that some people could visit the site at midnight, so just saying that is a separate session if it happens on a separate day may not be a good strategy.